# what is the procedure of performing wsdl parsing in iphone?

Tags: iphone

**i have performed like this**  **Is there any thing wrong performed by me?**
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://111.111.111.111/BattleEmpire.Service/ApplicationService.svc?wsdl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog( @"connection established");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

Comment: That depends on what you expect. If you expect it to parse wsdl, then you need to add more code to do the parsing.
The code snippet you posted only takes care of initating the loading of the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the parsing of the WSDL web service Referrer this site:http://sudzc.com/Default.aspx
It also provides Video how to parse such kind of Web Service.It's really helpful and so simple to implement..